# issues with create an opencv window

Tags: opencv, xcode4.6

I have Mac OS Lion 10.7.5 and xCode 4.6. I've downloaded an [opencv template](https://github.com/foundry). Then retrive a framework and want to create my own project. For the first i install cmake 2.8.10, add a framework and that's it. In main.m i try to create a window:

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
   #import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("1.png", 8);
   cvNamedWindow("Example",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //Thread 1: signal SIGANRT

    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

And in debug area i got following:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /Volumes/minijHome/Documents/xcode_mini/hillegass/advancedIOS/postCourse/openCV/clean-downloads/openCVgitClone/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 652
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

What i have to do?

Comment: You need to build opencv with clang and clang++ on osx.  I tried everything while using gcc and g++, and this was the only solution.